# drawRect not called when subclassing UIView and adding it in the interface builder

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I am trying to subclass UIView. Code like so:

```
import UIKit

class CustomView: UIView {


    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
        // Drawing code
        let circlePath = UIBezierPath(ovalInRect: rect)
        UIColor.blueColor().setFill()
        circlePath.fill()
    }
```

}

I have dragged a UIView onto a UIViewController and set the class to CustomView however the circle doesn't appear (I have set the constraints correctly). Any ideas what I might be doing wrong here? I'm not trying to preview it. Just want to see it when I run the app. Seems I am getting an error in the console too: `Unknown class _TtC9MyProject15CustomView in Interface Builder file.`

Answer (score 1):

It is likely that the *Target Membership* for your *CustomView.swift* file is not set for your app.

In the *Project Navigator* on the far left, select your file *CustomView.swift*.  Then in the *File Navigator* on the far right under **Target Membership**, make sure the box to the left of your app name is checked.